# Date/time field is not populating although syntax is working

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime

I would like to combine a date and a time value, based on the condition, that the "time of the day" field is set to "Morning (09:00 - 13:00)". The syntax is working but when I look into the field, it is always still blank. Does anybody have a hint?

```
IF(
    text(Time_of_the_Day__c) = "Morning (09:00 - 13:00)",
    DATETIMEVALUE(text(Date__c) + " " + "09:00") + 8 / 24,
    DATETIMEVALUE(text(Date__c) + " " + "14:00") + 8 / 24
)
```

Comment: have you tested what the output of text(Date__c) + " " + "09:00" is? It might not be in the right format for DATETIMEVALUE..

Answer (score 0):

What field type is Time_of_the_Day__c? Is it a picklist value? If so, have you tried ISPICKVAL() instead?

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Time_of_the_Day__c, "Morning (09:00 - 13:00"),
    DATETIMEVALUE(text(Date__c) + " " + "09:00") + 8 / 24,
    DATETIMEVALUE(text(Date__c) + " " + "14:00") + 8 / 24
)
```

If not a picklist field, which field type is it?

Comment: Hi Neil. For picklist fields, ISPICKVAL(fieldname, "field value") effectively has the same outcome as TEXT(fieldname) = "field value"

Comment: Thank you @GuyClairbois -- I appreciate the clarification.